# I want to know how i can change or select transfer functions in AVNNET in CARET package?

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to know how can i change or select transfer functions such as logsig or tansig in AVNNET in CARET package?

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever the [`nnet` function](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/nnet/nnet) can do.

Comment: thanks topepo but i cant find relevant arguments in nnet? please explain more. thanks again